# OCMock report error from stub

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I want to test that my code properly handles a particular error returned from `dataWithContentsOfFile`.  The problem is that the error isn't specifically **returned** from the method, it is an output parameter (passed in as `NSError **`.

It is easy enough for me to simply have the mock return `nil` from the stub, but I want to specifically test that the error it outputs is handled.  How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is described in section 2.5 (Returning values in pass-by-reference arguments) in the documentation: http://ocmock.org/reference/#stubing-methods

Comment: Perfect, I can't believe I overlooked that.